# Unreachable variable while working with Google AdWords API in PHP

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I have a problem in PHP and I can't seem to solve it. I am using Google AdWords API to create campaigns. So first of all I create a new Campaign, and after that new GroupAd. Problem is that I get campaign ID when creating campaign, and although I save that ID in variable $mycampaignID, I can't use it in another class where I am creating GroupAd. Can someone help me with this? I tried using global variable, public variable, etc., but none of it seems to work properly. Here is just a part of the code, you can see how classes and function look like.

```
   class AddCampaigns
    {



        public static function runExample(
            AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
            AdWordsSession $session
        ) {
            $result = $campaignService->mutate($operations);
            foreach ($result->getValue() as $campaign) {
                **$mycampaignID** = $campaign->getId();
                printf(
                    "Campaign with name '%s' and ID %d was added.\n",
                    $campaign->getName(),
                    $campaign->getId()
                );
            }
        }


    }

    AddCampaigns::main();


    class AddAdGroups
    {
        const CAMPAIGN_ID = **$mycampaignID**;

        public static function runExample(
            AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
            AdWordsSession $session,
            $campaignId
        ) {
            $adGroupService = $adWordsServices->get($session, AdGroupService::class);
        }

    }

    AddAdGroups::main();
```